GitHub issue during "git push origin main"
During pushing last changes of data on my local machine to GitHub repository, I am facing with such issue:
 RPC failed; HTTP 400 curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 3 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)

I have pro version and already deleted large file (83Mb) from local folder. But during transferring changes GitHub:
Enumerating objects: 64, done.
Counting objects: 100% (55/55), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (43/43), done.
Writing objects: 100% (43/43), 335.42 MiB | 18.22 MiB/s, done.
Total 43 (delta 25), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0 (from 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (25/25), completed with 7 local objects.
remote: warning: File random_forest_feature_selection_model.pkl is 81.97 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: warning: File random_forest_feature_selection_model.pkl is 86.35 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: warning: File random_forest_feature_selection_model.pkl is 89.22 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: error: Trace: 5234691ba2b9d8afdfc2f8b8394210c75fa33d5cf5e62264e9b9e80feb77139e
remote: error: See https://gh.io/lfs for more information.
remote: error: File random_forest_feature_selection_model.pkl is 405.55 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File random_forest_feature_selection_model.pkl is 405.55 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://github.com/BorysZhyhalo/TemaBit-Fozzy-Group.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)

Push/save last changes of data on my local machine to GitHub repository.

Did you read your error message? File random_forest_feature_selection_model.pkl is 405.55 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB - you obviously cannot upload a file that is this large. Read man git-lfs for one of available options.

How did you "already delete the file"? Creating a new commit removing the file doesn't actually delete it. You probably want to rewrite history using git commit --amend or similar.

If you want to remove that file from your repository, there are many answers on this site that will show you how to do that.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history

I think it's just a temporary problem, but just in case you can't fix it, you should switch the HTTP/2 stream to HTTP/1.1. I have left the command below.
git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1
If it doesn't work, could you provide the details of the error?
